# High rpms slow acceleration

Tags: ford, explorer

I have a 2003 ford explorer and if I drive it cold it will rev up higher than normal and move slow and it will be stuck like that for a couple of days then go back to normal if I let it warm up before taking off..what could this be?

Comment: Sounds like the transmission is slipping .. this is an automatic?

Comment: Just got the tranny redone..it shifts fine

Comment: Also no check engine light on

Comment: It will be stuck like that for a few days if i take off when its cold..few days will go by and all of a sudden it will run perfect....

Comment: Sounds like to me something is getting stuck..but cant figure out what

Comment: If you are running your engine up to higher revs and it's not moving, it's a transmission issue. Take it back to the shop which did the work and tell them there's something wrong with it.

Comment: It moves tho..and shifts fine

Comment: Ok its loud like a diesel truck..when its running fine its quiet

Comment: Its really hard to explain and i dont have money at all. Just paid 3000$ for a tranny job

Comment: All i can say is its not the tranny.. Its almost like lots of air coming out.. Way too much air

Comment: Britney, if you just got the transmission redone, and now this is happening - it's the transmission!

Comment: No this problem was before and after tranny work. Tranny is fine now..this problem continued

Comment: I think i figured out..the fan clutch or something of that sort

Comment: what is a fan clutch?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a 4x4 model? If so could be a problem with the transfer case or you could be switching into LOW accidentally.

If you're capable, do a full diagnostic. It sounds like you may have more than one problem.

If you're not a real wrench monkey, take it back to the shop. If you're talking about the radiator fan, that could result in over heating and thus loss of power, but it wouldn't be intermittent.

Most problems with the power plant don't really come and go like that. That's usually what you find in something computer controlled like intake, injection and the *transmission*. Id honestly recommend taking your vehicle to another shop and having them check if the work you were billed was actually done correctly. If the shop messed up something that could easily cause this issue. But again, *it would be a transmission related problem*.